# How to compare integer numbers as stored as a days and month with date

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bucket

I have three tables, A with columns Invoice Date, Vendor, Table B with TAG, DAY, MONTH, Term and table C with Term and vendor
I want to find out no. of days calculating from invoice date by joining these three tables.

TAG is int column having values from 1 to 31. Basically it is days to compare if the invoice date is below TAG value then consider that specific rule in DAY and MONTH columns to calculate the no. of days from the invoice.

DAY is the day of the month, MONTH is the number of months to be considered

for e.g. First row, if invoice date is 7/2/23 which is lower then the TAG i.e. 16th day of the month then it should takes AA5 Term with DAY 20 to calculate no. of days from invoice date so no. of days will be 13

```
Table A                 Table B                        Table C
Inv_Dt    Vendor  |  TAG     DAY    MONTH   Term  |   Vendor     Term
7/02/23   100428  |  16     20      00      AA5   |   100428      AA5
17/3/23   100428  |  25     20      01      AA5   |   100428      AA5
26/3/23   100428  |  31     10      02      AA5   |   100428      AA5
22/4/23   100429  |  26     07      02      CA2   |   100429      CA2

Desried Output :

Inv_Dt    Vendor   TAG     DAY    MONTH    Term   No. of days
7/02/23   100428   16     20      00      AA5      13      (13 Days of Feb)
17/3/23   100428   25     20      01      AA5      34      (14 Days of Mar + 20 Days of Apr)
26/3/23   100428   31     10      02      AA5      45   (5 Days of Mar + 30 days of Apr + 10 Day of May)
22/4/23   100429   26     07      02      CA2      46     (8 Days of Apr + 31 days of May + 7 days of June)
```

Comment: Why is the last row assigned a non-existing(!) TAG 26 but using TAG 18?

Comment: @Gustav sorry, It was a typo. I have corrected

Comment: Can you explain how rows of tableA and B are joined? 15/3/23 is also less than tag 16 so why it is not joined with first row? Please explain logic how did you count values for next rows. Also are rows joined through TERM?

Comment: Hi - you've explained what the rule is if the day is less than the tag, but what are the rules if the day is equal to, or greater than, the tag?

Comment: Hi @PonderStibbons Yes, tables joined based on Term and I have corrected the 2nd row details.

Comment: Also, as (for example) '7/02/23' is less than both tag = 16 and tag = 25, what are the rules for which record to use?

Comment: Hi @NickW Invoice_dt day is less than or equal to the tag then same rule, if invoice date is greater then tag then if the next greater tag is available then that rule. because tag is nothing but days of the month. so it cannot be greater than 31

Comment: @NickW For `7/02/23` It should take tag =16 rule only because we have multiple term tag for same term. Can it be done using bucketing of tags so for e.g. 0-16, 17-25 and 26-31

Comment: OK. I understood logic, here is [SQL Server solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/DmGlzrlE). Unfortunately I do not know Snowflake.

Comment: Hello @PonderStibbons 
Thank you so much for your response. It seems to be the correct solution. I am working to build the same query on snowflake. I have total 3 tables in SF. Table A with inv_dt and vendor, Table B same as mentioned and Table C with vendor and Term and I am unable to join 3 tables as per your solution. Could you please help.

Comment: @PonderStibbons I have corrected the question and added table C

Comment: Looks like joining A and C works: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lR-D6b3S).

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thank you, Should I run the query with all join together ? and in line no. 6 you have selected a.term and in line no. 13 you have joined a but we don't have term in table a 

I am getting error of (dateadd(month, n, inv_dt)) saying month is not a valid date/time component for function DATEADD

Comment: Documentation for [dateadd()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd) in Snowflake lists `month` as one of valid periods, which can be used, also one of the examples uses it.
Letter `a` in my query is an alias for subquery `joined`. You can write `select a.id from my_table a`. Please look at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kxZsxrQs), last two examples.

Comment: @PonderStibbons I tried this [https://dbfiddle.uk/T03RZ-LM] query in snowflake, It is showing as object B does not exist

Comment: 'b' is your second table, I do not know it's real name, in your original question you said "table B". Use it in query with alias: "... from MyTableName as b".

Comment: @PonderStibbons I tried. so, with join and till line no. 13 in your main query It is alias a and then in cross apply it is considering table B I tried same  and now it is showing that `SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`

Comment: Sorry, can't help with strictly Snowflake related question.

Comment: @PonderStibbons
It would be great if you just explain in SQL only. for quick 2 min
I really appreciate. Could you please join the meet ?

Comment: I really think I did what I could here, explanation, working dbfiddles in SQL Server. I have no access to Snowflake or knowledge of Snowflake. Please ask new question, show your current query, people will help if question is clear.

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thank you so much for the help here. Really appreciate. Can I use this sql query for the new question ?